# SQL query on Spark Kafka steam

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm reading binlogs from MySQL and pushing the changes to kafka topics. Then the topics are read as kafka stream in spark. How to convert the stream into spark temp table and run SQL like queries on it?

Here's my code

```
private static StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("id",  DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("code", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
    });
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Spark3App")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "topic")
                .load()
                .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data"));

        final StreamingQuery start = df.writeStream()
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
                .outputMode("append")
                .format("memory")
                .queryName("temp")
        spark.sql("select * from temp").show();
        start.awaitTermination();
```

Comment: what is the problem you have? you should be able to do `select * from causes`

Comment: the query executes only once and doesn't print anything and upon new data arriving into the stream, the query doesn't execute.